# CUDA Errors while running "CUDA By Example" julia_gpu.cu

Tags: c, cuda

I am running the example `julia_gpu.cu` from the book *CUDA By Example*, using CUDA 6.0 in Visual Studio Express 2012. Here's the source code for reference:

```
#include <book.h>
#include <cpu_bitmap.h>

#define DIM 1000

struct cuComplex {
    float   r;
    float   i;
    cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a), i(b)  {}
    __device__ float magnitude2( void ) {
        return r * r + i * i;
    }
    __device__ cuComplex operator*(const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r*a.r - i*a.i, i*a.r + r*a.i);
    }
    __device__ cuComplex operator+(const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r+a.r, i+a.i);
    }
};

__device__ int julia( int x, int y ) {
    const float scale = 1.5;
    float jx = scale * (float)(DIM/2 - x)/(DIM/2);
    float jy = scale * (float)(DIM/2 - y)/(DIM/2);

    cuComplex c(-0.8, 0.156);
    cuComplex a(jx, jy);

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
        a = a * a + c;
        if (a.magnitude2() > 1000)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

__global__ void kernel( unsigned char *ptr ) {
    // map from blockIdx to pixel position
    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y;
    int offset = x + y * gridDim.x;

    // now calculate the value at that position
    int juliaValue = julia( x, y );
    ptr[offset*4 + 0] = 255 * juliaValue;
    ptr[offset*4 + 1] = 0;
    ptr[offset*4 + 2] = 0;
    ptr[offset*4 + 3] = 255;
}

// globals needed by the update routine
struct DataBlock {
    unsigned char   *dev_bitmap;
};

int main( void ) {
    DataBlock   data;
    CPUBitmap bitmap( DIM, DIM, &data );
    unsigned char    *dev_bitmap;

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_bitmap, bitmap.image_size() ) );
    data.dev_bitmap = dev_bitmap;

    dim3    grid(DIM,DIM);
    kernel<<<grid,1>>>( dev_bitmap );

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( bitmap.get_ptr(), dev_bitmap,
                              bitmap.image_size(),
                              cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( dev_bitmap ) );

    bitmap.display_and_exit();
}
```

Building the above yielded a series of errors, which were all of the same form:

```
Error   2   error : calling a __host__ function("cuComplex::cuComplex") from a __device__ function("julia") is not allowed
Error   4   error : calling a __host__ function("cuComplex::cuComplex") from a __device__ function("cuComplex::operator *") is not allowed
Error   5   error : calling a __host__ function("cuComplex::cuComplex") from a __device__ function("cuComplex::operator +") is not allowed
```

...and so on.

I am having trouble understanding what the problem is, since as far as I was aware, `__device__` functions (like `julia`) are free to call and create `struct` objects (like `cuComplex`). What exactly is the problem here? Is the code provided in *CUDA By Example* (which was written back in 2010) broken by some of the changes introduced in the more recent CUDA 6.0 update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have already submitted errata to CUDA team some time ago (without any response yet), the solution is to simply add `__device__` qualifier for constructor:

```
__device__ cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a), i(b)  {}
```

Comment: So does that mean that when the book was written, the __device__ qualifier was not needed, but became necessary with later versions of CUDA? Or is it just a typo? Thanks for the response, it worked.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: It's just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `cuComplex` constructor from a device function, which you can't because its a host function.

You can try defining the constructor to be device as well, but I'm not sure it will work.